# PrestaShop: How to delete un-needed multistores as site taking too long to load?

Tags: themes, prestashop

So I installed a new Prestashop with theme sp_shoppy. The theme along with its default layout has auto-intalled multistores with different layouts (layout2 and layout3) whereas i only need the default layout of theme i.e layout1. Now because of this,most probably, my site is taking too long to load like its taking about 3 to 4 minutes to load completely. i am guessing this is due to multistores which i dont need. Also the zip file of my theme is still in my hosting should i delete it now as theme is installed.?

link to my site is : [My site](http://www.gotakinari.co.uk)

Answer (score 0):

For sure this is not because of multi-store, PrestaShop doesn't need to load all datas related to all stores if you visit one specific store.

I suggest you to contact with theme author, I guess you bought this theme somewhere?